# C# error when update database 2008 to sql 2016

Tags: c#, sql

I use software connect to sql database 2008 using OK, but i tranfers database 2008 to database 2016 (restore).

This software display errors:

> error loaddata: invalid column name

[image]

Comment: Please show us the code that is causing that exception.

Comment: Then you have an invalid column name.  I suggest looking at the actual code instead of just at pictures of the user interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, this is first time i use stackoverflow, so i write question unclear.
My question, self fixed. 
Cause: at SQL 2008 R2, Store Procedure i code false

> select l1..colname as a from table l1

this code can run at sql 2008. But can not run at SQL high level 2012, 2016, 2017.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WEvQ4.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qeVXv.png)
Thanks All,